# Где взять файл нужной версии?

Tags: debian

Тем у кого `ldd (Debian GLIBC 2.19-18) 2.19` (узнать командой `ldd --version`), помогите по братски, скиньте мне файл из каталога `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`, называется файл `libm.so.6`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

файл ldd входит в пакет:

```
$ dpkg -S $(which ldd)
libc-bin: /usr/bin/ldd
```

смотрим версии пакета `libc-bin`: https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libc-bin&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all

нужная версия `2.19-18` входит в состав версии *jessie*.

смотрим в какой пакет входит libm:

```
$ dpkg -S /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 
libc6:amd64: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
```

скачиваем его: https://packages.debian.org/jessie/libc6 (попутно убедившись, что файл имеется [в данной версии пакета для нужной архитектуры](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/libc6/filelist)):

```
$ wget http://mirror.yandex.ru/debian/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6_2.19-18+deb8u10_amd64.deb
```

распаковываем:

```
$ dpkg-deb -R файл.deb каталог
```

или сразу устанавливаем:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i файл.deb
```

---

p.s. вообще файл `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6` — это символическая ссылка на файл с актуальной версией библиотеки.