# sudoers: default secure path изменил

Tags: debian, sudo

Я изменил sudoers файл в процессе инсталяции судо пакета, изменил случайно, и не знаю его стандартное значение, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Суть проблемы в том, что перестали работать некоторые стандартные пакеты типа

```
uptime # и некоторые другие
```

Как исправить проблему?

Comment: Что конкретно означает "перестали работать"? В чём это выражается? Насколько я знаю, команде uptime никоим образом не нужно sudo.

Comment: Пишет не найдена команда, логично же, я перебил $path же сменную, просто упустил часть путей отвечающих за эти утилы.

Answer (score 0):

содержимое файла можно взять из файла с пакетом. в вашем случае имя пакета — `sudo`. все действия отлично выполняются от имени непривилегированного пользователя:

1. скачайте файл с пакетом в текущий каталог:

   ```
   $ apt download имя-пакета
   ```
2. распакуйте его:

   ```
   $ dpkg-deb -R *.deb каталог
   ```

`каталог/etc/sudoers` — это и есть искомый вами файл.

редактировать файл `/etc/sudoers` лучше программой-обёрткой *visudo*.

---

связанный вопрос: [Где взять файл нужной версии?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/895658/178576)